# in multiline text display whole word in single line - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, autosize

[image]

I have a row with an image and a text(wrapped inside Expanded widget), though it solves my purpose but it displays a single word in 2 lines when the word is long. Any way to display the word in a single line only(even if it wants to resize the whole text)

Comment: add maxLines : 1 in your Text() widget

Answer (score 0):

may be this link can help you https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html
this is textview with auto resizable own size behavior